# version `GLIBC_2.32' not found error when running petalinux-build

Tags: linux, fedora, glibc, petalinux

I'm trying to build PetaLinux image as described here: [tutorial](https://xilinx.github.io/Embedded-Design-Tutorials/docs/2021.1/build/html/docs/Introduction/Zynq7000-EDT/4-linux-for-zynq.html#creating-a-petalinux-image).
To build it I'm using Fedora 33, which is not officially supported but usually there are workarounds.
I'm having problems with the command `petalinux-build` (step 3), after some computation it prints a quite long log on the terminal, stating in particular that:

```
Subprocess output:
/home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps: 
/home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib64/libgomp.so.1)
```

However if I run `ldd --version`, I get:

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.32
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

And if I run `/lib/libc.so.6`, I get:

```
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.32.
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1).
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.
```

So it seems to me that I do have the correct version of glibc installed, so what is the problem?

This is the full error output, the glibc part is under "Subprocess output":

```
ERROR: xtrans-1_1.3.5-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch 5ee34dd31a0dd2a70bfb8dddb8e1777f versus e43051180f334754f374d0bd97e81203 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/xtrans_1.3.5.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 5ee34dd31a0dd2a70bfb8dddb8e1777f versus e43051180f334754f374d0bd97e81203 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/xtrans_1.3.5.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: base-passwd-3.5.29-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch c3837ed788613b3e1c7d4861734cdb8a versus a4b211e338ce900b232a6e2c185111c3 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-core/base-passwd/base-passwd_3.5.29.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch c3837ed788613b3e1c7d4861734cdb8a versus a4b211e338ce900b232a6e2c185111c3 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-core/base-passwd/base-passwd_3.5.29.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: gdbm-1.13-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch b922a2087e73e51e9d01436c1e4e248e versus 1aef7bb409901a0048b90eba2479eede for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-support/gdbm/gdbm_1.13.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch b922a2087e73e51e9d01436c1e4e248e versus 1aef7bb409901a0048b90eba2479eede for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-support/gdbm/gdbm_1.13.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: cryptodev-linux-1.9-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch 1cdcdec957d1856fea3457e369648880 versus 9b17b155f770ac0aa825eada166aa161 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-kernel/cryptodev/cryptodev-linux_1.9.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 1cdcdec957d1856fea3457e369648880 versus 9b17b155f770ac0aa825eada166aa161 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-kernel/cryptodev/cryptodev-linux_1.9.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: openssl-1.0.2l-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch ab1dbe098c8359940e77710633acbd94 versus f58213bd7e2f3020d2d90df2b2a5c60d for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl/openssl_1.0.2l.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch ab1dbe098c8359940e77710633acbd94 versus f58213bd7e2f3020d2d90df2b2a5c60d for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl/openssl_1.0.2l.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch 3edb04d402fa6d3395b4bd260a6cf005 versus 09f36ade6285df676e1c6231ea5d4e46 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_1.0.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 3edb04d402fa6d3395b4bd260a6cf005 versus 09f36ade6285df676e1c6231ea5d4e46 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_1.0.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_unpack: Taskhash mismatch cec2ffc0af098e6b656f3a4e10cf8bac versus 6d9ef0dccf4a30521b5b89ecad5de347 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_1.0.bb.do_unpack
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch cec2ffc0af098e6b656f3a4e10cf8bac versus 6d9ef0dccf4a30521b5b89ecad5de347 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_1.0.bb.do_unpack
ERROR: xcb-proto-1.12-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch 061b329f97e940c0d8ec4a2b3d7c9f77 versus e767d8d505fde7d26fc7a73b1f76dc91 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-proto/xcb-proto_1.12.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 061b329f97e940c0d8ec4a2b3d7c9f77 versus e767d8d505fde7d26fc7a73b1f76dc91 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-proto/xcb-proto_1.12.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: libpthread-stubs-0.4-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch 4c847cd7da4e14c81d7661edcffb2d16 versus ba33c70d08a20f071d5cd39e166467f4 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/libpthread-stubs_0.4.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 4c847cd7da4e14c81d7661edcffb2d16 versus ba33c70d08a20f071d5cd39e166467f4 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/libpthread-stubs_0.4.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: libxdmcp-1_1.1.2-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch 40aab1d9821aeb05e85d8c92094741f5 versus 77bed6e51edda4307a4524745cf94609 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/libxdmcp_1.1.2.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 40aab1d9821aeb05e85d8c92094741f5 versus 77bed6e51edda4307a4524745cf94609 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/libxdmcp_1.1.2.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: libxau-1_1.0.8-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch 7e6bb150c02427b0ea8816f2d835748a versus e01f44ab47147ed68c5e698beebb7f77 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/libxau_1.0.8.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 7e6bb150c02427b0ea8816f2d835748a versus e01f44ab47147ed68c5e698beebb7f77 for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/libxau_1.0.8.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: linux-libc-headers-4.12-r0 do_package: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:package_do_filedeps(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/classes/package.bbclass', lineno: 1484, function: package_do_filedeps
     1480:            continue
     1481:        for files in chunks(pkgfiles[pkg], 100):
     1482:            pkglist.append((pkg, files, rpmdeps, pkgdest))
     1483:
 *** 1484:    processed = oe.utils.multiprocess_exec( pkglist, oe.package.filedeprunner)
     1485:
     1486:    provides_files = {}
     1487:    requires_files = {}
     1488:
File: '/home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/lib/oe/utils.py', lineno: 240, function: multiprocess_exec
     0236:        mapresult = pool.map_async(function, commands, error_callback=failures)
     0237:
     0238:        pool.close()
     0239:        pool.join()
 *** 0240:        results = mapresult.get()
     0241:    except KeyboardInterrupt:
     0242:        pool.terminate()
     0243:        pool.join()
     0244:        raise
File: '/usr/lib64/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py', lineno: 771, function: get
     0767:            raise TimeoutError
     0768:        if self._success:
     0769:            return self._value
     0770:        else:
 *** 0771:            raise self._value
     0772:
     0773:    def _set(self, i, obj):
     0774:        self._success, self._value = obj
     0775:        if self._callback and self._success:
Exception: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps', '--alldeps', '/home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.12-r0/packages-split/linux-libc-headers-lic/usr/share/licenses/linux-libc-headers/generic_GPLv2', '/home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.12-r0/packages-split/linux-libc-headers-lic/usr/share/licenses/linux-libc-headers/COPYING']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Subprocess output:
/home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.12-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps: /home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib64/libgomp.so.1)

ERROR: linux-libc-headers-4.12-r0 do_package: Function failed: package_do_filedeps
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.12-r0/temp/log.do_package.227243
ERROR: Task (/home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-kernel/linux-libc-headers/linux-libc-headers_4.12.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: libffi-3.2.1-r0 do_fetch: Taskhash mismatch ca914d97dfb9f8448699567a97575997 versus 1e247b18753a9f2165aee681b9a87c8e for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-support/libffi/libffi_3.2.1.bb.do_fetch
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch ca914d97dfb9f8448699567a97575997 versus 1e247b18753a9f2165aee681b9a87c8e for /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-support/libffi/libffi_3.2.1.bb.do_fetch
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 794 tasks of which 743 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/MY_USER/path/Project/PetaLinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/core/meta/recipes-kernel/linux-libc-headers/linux-libc-headers_4.12.bb:do_package
Summary: There were 3 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 26 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
ERROR: Failed to build project
```

If any other information is needed please ask and I will provide it.
Thanks!

Comment: Guessing : Your default glibc-2.32 is the wrong architecture ? Is x86_64 ? ..... and the xilinx arch is `aarch, arm64` ? ....... You are supposed to use an aarch glibc ........

Comment: Yes my glibc is the x86_64 and I think I xilinx is arm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `/home/MY_USER/.../sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib64/libgomp.so.1)`

You are mixing *system* `libgomp.so.1` with *sysroot* `libc.so.6` -- this will never end well. You *probably* need to build `libgomp.so.1` in the sysroot as well.

> And if I run `/lib/libc.so.6`, I get:

That is *irrelevant* -- you link isn't failing with that library, but with the sysroot one.

If you run `/home/MY_USER/path/Project/xilinx-zc702-2018.2/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/libc.so.6`, you'll see that it is in fact too old (older than `2.32`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in what seems the right direction, I have little time now but I managed to run what you suggested and it returns `GNU C Library (GNU libc) development release version 2.25.90`, so what I should do is to replace this library with the newer one?

Comment: I tried to replace the library in a couple of ways but it didn't work. So now I'd like to try to build `libgomp.so.1` in my project, how would I do it?

Comment: @overmach This answer answered your "what is the problem?" question. You should accept it and ask a new question: "why is my petalinux build using system libgomp" or "how to use newer GLIBC in petalinux build", or similar. I have _no idea_ what petalinux is, and can't help with that.

Comment: I have opened another question to solve the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243564/building-libgomp-so-1-in-sysroot

Comment: @EmployedRussian could you answer my question please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481326/how-to-add-php-to-petalinux