# How to add PHP to PetaLinux?

Tags: php, yocto, xilinx, petalinux, yocto-recipe

I want to set up a web server on Petalinux, currently, Petalinux has apache on its menu, and it works fine, but I want to add PHP to Petalinux as well.
for this purpose I added **CONFIG_php** statement to **user-rootfsconfig** file in  '*/project-spec/meta-user/conf*' path.

After I ran `Petalinux-config -c rootfs` and check 'PHP' in user packages, and then I built the project.
I saw Petalinux build process downloaded and compiled PHP( from logs it prints in terminal) but when I copied rootfs on SD-Card and boot the Linux, PHP doesn't exist.

How could I add PHP to Petalinux properly?

**NOTE** : I use petalinux 2021 and there is PHP recipe in '*/components/yocto/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools*' path.

Comment: I do the current process for iperf3 and it works properly, but still, PHP and NodeJs don't exist in rootfs

Comment: Just a suggestion: if the work u want to perform on the server side is possible using C, python, perl or similar scripting language the you can try doing the same with CGI (Common gateway Interface). Coz IN my project I had to write to some file in the server side. This i am able to perform using CGI. You can give it a try. Let me know if you want any help regarding this. I caN HELP YOU OUT WITH THIS.